# Can I use android emulator in my 32-bit Windows 8 Pro with Installed memory(RAM) 3GB

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I have started using Xamarin with visual Studio and noticed that to use built-in Android emulator in Visual Studio it requires that [Windows 8 Pro with 64-bit with 6GB or more RAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx) . So I decided to use Android SDK instead of using android emulator provided by Visual Studio. Now I am installing Android Studio on my PC. And on Android official webpage to install on windows it requires 3GB RAM minimum; plus 1GB for Android Emulator. Link is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). It is also stated that it support for operating system Windows 7/8/10( 32- or 64-bit). I feel little bit confused. Do you think I can be able to run Android emulator on my PC? Or can you advice me other way of how to test my adroid application.

Comment: Install android x86 in virtual machine. Sounds crazy but once you figure out the display settings and so, you will have a real emulator. Faster than any built in. http://www.android-x86.org take a look.

Comment: I believe the only to find out is if you test it for yourself. But I recommend using the Genymotion emulator. It is a bit faster than the Android Studio one

Comment: Try the OS in itself. Much better to look in console and debug:))

Comment: thank you all:). Hi @RosárioPereiraFernandes I have just looked up for Genymotion emulator requirements and found out that it requires VT-x or AMD-V capability. Sincemy PC is Pentium dual-core T4300 it does not have VT-x. Do you have other advice guys?

Comment: hi @user3344236 , what do you mean by using OS itself? can you help me to understand :)